# What is the advantage of using the same lifetime for multiple arguments?

Tags: rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

```
fn xory<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str { x }
```

What is the advantage of the above code over using two lifetimes? Are there any situations in which the above code will work, but 2 lifetimes won't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your use case. Given the exact code you wrote:

```
fn xory<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str { 
    x 
}
```

Here it is an disadvantage to use only one lifetime, because the return value only depends on the `x` argument, not on the `y` one. Let's imagine this user code:

```
let x_in = "paul".to_owned();
let out = {
    let y_in = "peter".to_owned();
    xory(&x_in, &y_in)
};
```

We would expect that this works fine, because `out` is basically `x_in`. But the compiler complains:

```
<anon>:12:22: 12:26 error: `y_in` does not live long enough
<anon>:12         xory(&x_in, &y_in)
                               ^~~~
<anon>:13:7: 14:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 13:6...
<anon>:13     };
<anon>:14 }
<anon>:11:39: 13:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 11:38
<anon>:11         let y_in = "peter".to_owned();
<anon>:12         xory(&x_in, &y_in)
<anon>:13     };
```

This is because the compiler assumes (from the `xory` signature) that the output from `xory` references both arguments. So it's often better to specify lifetimes as detailed as possible to avoid unnecessary conditions/assumptions/relationships between parameters.

---

In some cases you need to use only one lifetime (or a slightly different solution): suppose you want to return either `x` or `y` depending on some condition:

```
fn xory<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str { 
    if x.len() == 42 { 
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

Here the lifetime of the output can depend on both arguments' lifetimes and we don't know on which one at compile time. Therefore we have to prepare for the worst and do it like this.

Comment: Oh,  the output has to unify if it depends on both inputs.

Answer (score 1):

With the same lifetime you're saying that the return value could be borrowed from either `x` or `y`, so from the point of view of the function body, it's more flexible.
From the caller it's more restrictive as both `x` and `y` need to be valid for as long as the result is kept, rather than just `x` (say).